# How do I display echo after form submit on return to html page?

Tags: php

This will show the echo on a blank white page.

```
$existsQuery = "select count(*) as count from entry where emailaddress like '".$_POST[emailaddress]."'";
$existsResult = mysqli_query($con, $existsQuery);

if($existsResult->fetch_object()->count > 0)
{
    echo "email already exist";
    /* header('index.html?email=exists'); */
}
```

I want to show the echo under the submit button on the main html page. Is using the URL a good way and how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is using the URL a good way and how do I do it?

I think that's a good solution, so the code would look like this:

```
$existsQuery = "select count(*) as count from entry where emailaddress like '".$_POST[emailaddress]."'";
$existsResult = mysqli_query($con, $existsQuery);

if($existsResult->fetch_object()->count > 0)
{
    header('index.html?email=exists');
}
```

and then you can do this right below the button `submit` button in your `form`:

```
<?= if (isset($_GET["email"]) && $_GET["email"] == "exists") { echo "email already exists"; } ?>
```

Comment: I switched it to `header('Location: index2.html?email=exists');` so it actually redirects but nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Add this line `<?= echo $_QUERY["email"]; ?>` on the page and see what the value of `email` is when you redirect.

Comment: My form is like `<form name="entry" action="entry.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();"  method="post">` The above code is in entry.php. The redirect takes you back to index2.html?email=exists and nothing shows up. Am I missing like <?php ?> tags or something?

Comment: @AndrewBrigance, please see my edit, I modified the code that should go in the `index2.html` page by the `submit` button inside your `form`.

Comment: Ah, one thing you'll need to do, change the name of `index2.html` to be `index2.php` -I should have caught that right away!

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to do that.

Take a look at this example:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

You can start with the basics here http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp and then learn how to use the $_POST method to your specific case: